# How do I declare a variable number of generic variables in a Java class?

Tags: java, android

Say I have a Java class that has a constructor like:

```
public abstract class MyClass {

    public <A extends Alpha, B extends Beta> MyClass(A... clses, B... Bclses) {
    // where I can create this class with an arbitrary number of A's and B's fields.
        for (A a : clses) {
            storeAsFieldInMyClass(a);
        }
        for (B b : Bclses) {
            storeAsFieldInMyClass(b);
        }
    }
}
```

where I want to have an arbitrary number of A's and B's. One such example would be, in a RecyclerView.Adapter that uses Data Binding, multiple `ViewDataBinding` are used, i.e. for a chat RecyclerView, one for sent messages, one for received messages. A lot of the logic for setting it up is the same, however usually I might like 5 ViewHolders or 2 ViewHolders or just 1 ViewHolder, so I want a generic Adapter class to handle it all.

Comment: Use a `Map<String, A>` and a `Map<String, B>`. Or a `List<A>`. etc. Or, even better, find some union `interface C` and have both types implement it.

Comment: oh? then how do I get the viewdatabinding after I set it.